# OSX iTerm2 can use mouse with python-ncurses but not with curses in C

Tags: python, c, ncurses

I'm thinking about including mouse support to a small editor written in C. The editor is built around ncurses, so I thought it should be possible. I got this Python source from another post and it runs:

```
import curses
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def open_screen():
    scr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    scr.keypad(1)
    try:
        yield scr
    finally:
        curses.nocbreak()
        scr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()

curses_mouse_states = {
    curses.BUTTON1_PRESSED: 'Button 1 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON1_RELEASED: 'Button 1 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON1_CLICKED: 'Button 1 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON1_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 1 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON1_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 1 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON2_PRESSED: 'Button 2 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON2_RELEASED: 'Button 2 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON2_CLICKED: 'Button 2 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON2_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 2 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON2_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 2 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON3_PRESSED: 'Button 3 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON3_RELEASED: 'Button 3 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON3_CLICKED: 'Button 3 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON3_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 3 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON3_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 3 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON4_PRESSED: 'Button 4 Pressed', 
    curses.BUTTON4_RELEASED: 'Button 4 Released', 
    curses.BUTTON4_CLICKED: 'Button 4 Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON4_DOUBLE_CLICKED: 'Button 4 Double-Clicked',
    curses.BUTTON4_TRIPLE_CLICKED: 'Button 4 Triple-Clicked',

    curses.BUTTON_SHIFT: 'Button Shift', 
    curses.BUTTON_CTRL: 'Button Ctrl', 
    curses.BUTTON_ALT: 'Button Alt'
}

with open_screen() as scr:
    curses.mousemask(-1)
    while True:
        c = scr.getch()
        if c == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
            gmouse = curses.getmouse()
            mouse_state = gmouse[4]
            states = '; '.join(state_string for state, state_string 
                               in curses_mouse_states.viewitems() 
                               if mouse_state & state)
            scr.addstr(0, 0, states)
            scr.clrtoeol()
            scr.addstr(1, 0, "x = %3d" % gmouse[1] )
            scr.addstr(2, 0, "y = %3d" % gmouse[2] )
            scr.refresh()
        elif c == ord('q'):
            break
```

But then, I have this source code in C:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WIDTH 30
#define HEIGHT 10 

int startx = 0;
int starty = 0;

char *choices[] = {     "Choice 1",
            "Choice 2",
            "Choice 3",
            "Choice 4",
            "Exit",
        };

int n_choices = sizeof(choices) / sizeof(char *);

void print_menu(WINDOW *menu_win, int highlight);
void report_choice(int mouse_x, int mouse_y, int *p_choice);

int main()
{   int c, choice = 0;
    WINDOW *myscreen, *menu_win;
    MEVENT  event;
    mmask_t oldmask;

    /* Initialize curses */
    myscreen = initscr();
    clear();
    noecho();
    cbreak();   //Line buffering disabled. pass on everything
    keypad(myscreen,TRUE);

    /* Try to put the window in the middle of screen */
    startx = (80 - WIDTH) / 2;
    starty = (24 - HEIGHT) / 2;

    attron(A_REVERSE);
    mvprintw(23, 1, "Click on Exit to quit (Works best in a virtual console)");
    refresh();
    attroff(A_REVERSE);

    /* Print the menu for the first time */
    menu_win = newwin(HEIGHT, WIDTH, starty, startx);
    print_menu(menu_win, 1);
    /* Get all the mouse events */
    mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, &oldmask);

    while(1)
    {
        c = wgetch(menu_win);
        switch(c) {
        case KEY_MOUSE:
            if(getmouse(&event) == OK)
            {   /* When the user clicks left mouse button */
                mvprintw(21,1,"Event: x = %3d y = %3d",event.x,event.y);

                if(event.bstate & BUTTON1_PRESSED)
                {   report_choice(event.x + 1, event.y + 1, &choice);
                    if(choice == -1) //Exit chosen
                        goto end;
                    mvprintw(22, 1, "Choice made is : %d String Chosen is \"%10s\"", choice, choices[choice - 1]);
                    refresh(); 
                }
            } else {
                mvprintw(21,1,"Couldn't get event!");
            }
            print_menu(menu_win, choice);
            break;
        case 'Q':
        case 'q': 
            goto end;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }       
end:
    mousemask(oldmask,&oldmask);
    nocbreak();
    keypad(myscreen,FALSE);
    echo();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}


void print_menu(WINDOW *menu_win, int highlight)
{
    int x, y, i;    

    x = 2;
    y = 2;
    box(menu_win, 0, 0);
    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i)
    {   if(highlight == i + 1)
        {   wattron(menu_win, A_REVERSE); 
            mvwprintw(menu_win, y, x, "%s", choices[i]);
            wattroff(menu_win, A_REVERSE);
        }
        else
            mvwprintw(menu_win, y, x, "%s", choices[i]);
        ++y;
    }
    wrefresh(menu_win);
}

/* Report the choice according to mouse position */
void report_choice(int mouse_x, int mouse_y, int *p_choice)
{   int i,j, choice;

    i = startx + 2;
    j = starty + 3;

    for(choice = 0; choice < n_choices; ++choice)
        if(mouse_y == j + choice && mouse_x >= i && mouse_x <= i + strlen(choices[choice]))
        {   if(choice == n_choices - 1)
                *p_choice = -1;     
            else
                *p_choice = choice + 1; 
            break;
        }
}
```

And this doesn't run. Apparently, the initialisation stuff is right and I'm starting to not understand the world :( Any help?

Comment: "*This doesn't run*" is not helpful. What is the **exact** problem? Does the code compile? Are there any errors/warnings during compilation? If it compiles, what happens when you run the binary? Does anything display? Have you tried debugging at all? Please [edit] your post and add as much information as possible about the issue.

Comment: There was more than adequate information provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in C is reading input from `menu_win` (the call on `wgetch(menu_win)`), but you did not call

```
keypad(menu_win, TRUE);
```

before, to enable *special keys*.  In ncurses, `KEY_MOUSE` will not be returned if you do not enable this mode.

The [`wgetch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Function-Keys) manpage says

> The following function keys, defined in `<curses.h>`,  might
>   be  returned  by  **getch**  if **keypad** has been enabled.  Note
>   that not all of these are  necessarily  supported  on  any
>   particular terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was mixing too many things in the first step :-)